# Does Django message middleware not work with app engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-middleware

I am trying to implement the message middleware in my Django App engine project but its giving the an error message like:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware mediautils.middleware: "No module named messages"
```

I have followed the link http://djangoadvent.com/1.2/messages-rest-us/ to implement it.  Is it not possible to use this middleware with Google App engine? and if so, is there any alternative to get the same functionality with Google app engine and Django?

What are the changes required to make it run on google app engine?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I used the following code to implement the same functionality:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Message
Message(user=request.user, message="Date Updated Successfully").put()
```

though

> request.user.message_set.create(message= "Data Updated Successfully")

was not working.

Answer (score 2):

The latest Django included in GAE [is 1.1](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django); the new messaging framework was added in 1.2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Amber. Is there any way I can implement it? I am using App Engine Patch. I have seen in the app engine documentation that we can import modules even from the development version and it will make the changes accordingly.

Comment: I think the django admin panel uses some kind of message module in google app engine.